# for loop through dictionary of DataFrames to get each dataframe seperatly in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

i have a dictionary which has multiple Dataframes:
[image: Dictionary of Dataframes]

I would like to disassemble the column "Value" into seperate Dataframes and the The name of the each Dataframe should be the appropriate key

This code does not work:

```
for value, key in zip(daten_para_dic.values(), daten_para_dic.keys()):
   '{}'.format(key) = value
```

It says "cannot assign to function call"

Could someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: That code does not work because you are trying something different. What do you want exactly? dictionary with key as dataframe_name and value as dataframe_value? or you want new variables with name as key and it's value to corresponding dataframe value?

Comment: @GodWin: Thank you.
I want to decompose dictionary into separate dataframes. The name of each dataframe shoul be the "key" from dictionary and the columns of each dataframe should be "value" from dictionary.

Comment: exactly the second part of your question @GodWin "or you want new variables with name as key and it's value to corresponding dataframe value?"

Comment: I also not properly understands, but can help you with the code you provided

Comment: for key in daten_para_dic.keys():
    print('you can access key by variable key')
    print('you can access dataframe value by variable daten_para_dic[key]')
    print('no need to use zip() function')

Comment: @iamawesome hello .. thank you .. actually i did not understand your solution

Comment: You cannot create dynamic variable like that till my knowledge.